# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/File;)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror

While trying to launch firefox browser using selenium

Function:

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constants.PROJECT_PATH+Constants.MARIONETTE_FIREFOX);
     log.info("Marionette file path: "+Constants.PROJECT_PATH+Constants.MARIONETTE_FIREFOX);
     MarionetteDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

In the 3rd line i am getting the mentioned error message -

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/File;)"
```

Maven Dependency tags I am using is

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

New dependecy tags added following #Christian Lutz answer

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I re-solve the issue?

Comment: inspect your runtime classpath and check version of commons-io which claims to have this method with exact this signature

Answer (score 12):

In version 1.3.2 the class `FileUtils`doesn't have a method `copyInputStreamToFile` you need at least version `2.0`

Please [see](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/index.html) the javadoc for the current version `2.5`. There you will find the method and a `Since`tag.

Comment: thanks for help, but it didn't worked out. Still displaying same error

Comment: Have you changed your dependency to `mvn:commons-io:commons-io:2.5`. Be aware that the group id has changed, too.

Comment: @MadhaviMokkapati Also I just checked the current pom of the web driver https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/pom.xml and they are using version 2.5 of commons-io.

Comment: @christan, yes i changed whole dependency tag, please find the updated tag in description.

Comment: @MadhaviMokkapati does this error occur during debugging? And / or running the your program itself? Is your classpath correct?

Comment: when i am running i got this error and i tried to debug. Browser not launched. " MarionetteDriverManager.getInstance().setup();" at this instruction execution failed with the mentioned error. Yes class path was correct, able to run in another browsers.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete stack trace. And are you using the current versions of the webdriver and firefox?

Answer (score -1):

I'am using Websphere 8.5.5.14 , in my case  i resolve the issue  by adding  the  commons-io-2.2.jar  as shared librarie .